# SQL Query from 4 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

I am using 3 tables to get certain number of records.
Following are my tables :

```
1.Order         - orderNumber,CustomerNumber
2. OrderDetails - orderNumber, productCode
3. Products     - productCode, productName
4. Customers    - CustomerNumber, CustomerName
```

Now for first 10 orders, I have to get orderNumber, CustomerName and productName from these 4 tables. I have done multiple queries but not able to get the desired results like :-

```
    select Orders.orderNumber, OrderDetails.productCode,Orders.customerNumber 
    from  Orders, OrderDetails 
    where Orders.orderNumber = OrderDetails.orderNumber limit 10;
```

Using this I am just trying to get just the orderNumber,productCode and CustomerNumber so I can build my query over this but it shows only one product from the Orders for each orderNumber instead of all the products inside a single orderNumber.

```
+-------------+-------------+----------------+
| orderNumber | productCode | customerNumber |
+-------------+-------------+----------------+
|       10100 | S18_1749    |            363 |
|       10100 | S18_2248    |            363 |
|       10100 | S18_4409    |            363 |
|       10100 | S24_3969    |            363 |
|       10101 | S18_2325    |            128 |
|       10101 | S18_2795    |            128 |
|       10101 | S24_1937    |            128 |
|       10101 | S24_2022    |            128 |
|       10102 | S18_1342    |            181 |
|       10102 | S18_1367    |            181 |
```

Edit 1:
From first 10 orders in Order table, I need to get corresponding OrderNumber, CustomerName and productName from given tables.

Edit 2:
Query result as per @simsim

```
 orderNumber | productCode | customerName                 |
+-------------+-------------+------------------------------+
|       10100 | S18_1749    | Online Diecast Creations Co. |
|       10100 | S18_2248    | Online Diecast Creations Co. |
|       10100 | S18_4409    | Online Diecast Creations Co. |
|       10100 | S24_3969    | Online Diecast Creations Co. |
|       10101 | S18_2325    | Blauer See Auto, Co.         |
|       10101 | S18_2795    | Blauer See Auto, Co.         |
|       10101 | S24_1937    | Blauer See Auto, Co.         |
|       10101 | S24_2022    | Blauer See Auto, Co.         |
|       10102 | S18_1342    | Vitachrome Inc.              |
|       10102 | S18_1367    | Vitachrome Inc.              |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear, please explain your goal more.

However, if I understood correctly, you want to get he Names also in your result "Product Name, and Customer Name", therefore, you might need to use Joins

**Example Query:**

```
SELECT
    OrderNumber,
    ProductCode,
    ProductName,
    CustomerNumber,
    CustomerName
FROM
(
    Select
        O.OrderNumber,
        P.ProductCode,
        P.ProductName,
        C.CustomerNumber,
        C.CustomerName
    From 
        Orders O
        INNER JOIN OrderDetails OD On
            O.OrderNumber = OD.OrderNumber
            INNER JOIN Products P On OD.ProductCode = P.ProductCode
        INNER JOIN Customers C On O.CustomerNumber = O.CustomerNumber
)
WHERE ROWNUM <= 10
```

Note: your query is half the way there

**Edit, based on your explanation:**

```
SELECT
        OrderNumber,
        ProductCode,
        ProductName,
        CustomerNumber,
        CustomerName
    FROM
    (
        Select
            O.OrderNumber,
            P.ProductCode,
            P.ProductName,
            C.CustomerNumber,
            C.CustomerName
        From 
            Orders O
            INNER JOIN OrderDetails OD On
                O.OrderNumber = OD.OrderNumber
                INNER JOIN Products P On OD.ProductCode = P.ProductCode
            INNER JOIN Customers C On O.CustomerNumber = O.CustomerNumber
        WHERE O.OrderNumber IN
        (
            SELECT OrderNumber FROM Orders
            WHERE ROWNUM <= 10
        )
    )
```

Comment: I am sorry for being ambiguous.Let me edit me question and verify your solution. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I am able to get the correct pattern but can't take just 10 orders. 
As per the above query, error is coming "unknown column" in first select statement.

Comment: you added a oracle tag, so if this is an oracle syntax, use the `ROWNUM` filter as in my answer, use ordering in the internal query, then filter it again as above

Comment: that just returns me top 10 rows but I want to have 10 orders. So if one order has multiple productCodes then it should return me 10 orders with more than 10 rows of productCodes and not just top rows.
Check my 2nd edit.

Comment: just to be clear, you have a number of orders, you want to get all the product codes for the top 10 orders ? for example, if each order has two products, this will result in 20 rows retrieved ?

Comment: Yes. I am sorry for confusion.

Comment: there is much smarter ways to do it, but this one will work

Comment: It's working but how can you also help me out in mysql as limit is not allowed in subquery?

Answer (score 0):

Try following if using Sql Server

select top 10 Orders.orderNumber,OrderDetails.productCode,Orders.customerNumber 
    from  Orders, OrderDetails 
    where Orders.orderNumber = OrderDetails.orderNumber ;

limit is not supported by all sql databases.